# 405 Method Not Allowed, add to cart flask python

Tags: python, flask

Im trying to do an add to cart method using flask and sqlalchemy. I am getting a 405 error saying the method is not allowed, and additionally dont think the method works as im unsure how to get the productID from the product page, when the button is clicked, to the add to cart method. Here is my views.py

```html
@app.route("/index", methods=['GET','POST'])
def addToCart():
    productID = int(request.form.get("productID"))
    isInCart = Cart.query.get(productID)
    userID = session['userID']
    if isInCart is None:
        c = Cart(userID=userID, productID=productID, quantity="1")
        db.session.add(c)
        db.session.commit()
    else:
        q = Cart.query.filter_by(userID=userID, productID=productID).first()
        oldQ = q.Quantity
        newQuantity = Cart.query.filter_by(userID=userID, productID=productID).update(dict(quantity= oldQ + 1))
        db.session.commit()
    return render_template("index.html" )
```

and here is my html i am using

```html
<form class="form" action="" method="post">
                                                                    <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart"/>
                                                                </form>
```

Please help its not working, i am using a cart database and a products database. If there are any suggestions on how i can get the code working please help

Answer (score 0):

**set action equal to '/index' in you html code**

```
<form class="form" action="/index" method="post">
   <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form is missing an action address. As per soham saoji's response, adding "/index" to your action should fix this but it might be better to use "url_for" so that it works beyond a development environment.

```html
<form class="form" action="{{ url_for('addToCart') }}" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Add to Cart"/>
</form>
```